# standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error" The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I am new to docker and for my learning purpose I followed the official nodejs docker instructons and followed the instructions but it keeps throwing error on the same command.

I tried making images docker on Raspberry Pi to be used as a server. but I have a problem building it to run it

this is Dockerfile me

```
FROM node:4.3.2
 WORKDIR /app
 RUN npm install
 EXPOSE (80)
 CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

ERROR

```
 docker build -t hello-world .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.212MB
Step 1/5 : FROM node:4.3.2
 ---> 3538b8c69182
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7b8a5c56f23d
Step 3/5 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in bbd6026d01d9
standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

and docker version

```
Containers: 19
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 19
Images: 10
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: extfs


Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.62-v7+
Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
OSType: linux
Architecture: armv7l
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 976.7MiB
Name: raspi2
ID: MJNK:BGTA:EFDS:B7VD:QZIL:T65S:IJRJ:ZO74:RG6D:BITS:AZNB:LDSC
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
   WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
   WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

Comment: The thing is, `node:4` image has not been available for a long time now. Upgrade to LTS (8) or latest release (10) and try again.

Comment: Looks like the architecture of your image does not match the architecture of your host. The armv71 isn't familiar to me, but I don't do much with raspberry pi's (yet).

Answer (score 0):

The `RUN` instruction has two writing [forms](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run).

In your case, you have chosen the `shell` form which `RUN` statement will be parsed to `/bin/sh -c run-statement(npm install here)`.

Unfortunately, it replies with `non-zero error`. We all should know, **shell script** will replies non-zero error when error occurs.

I am not familiar with `npm`. But still I may see that error is not related with docker now, but shell script itself.

Maybe it’s the syntax or npm version issue which is mentioned by other comment. It is not about docker platform now.

You could just upgrade npm image as comment said above. May this help~